# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

Hi all,

Thank you for your helpful [design input](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/405/design-mockups-for-final-site-theme). As you can see, the new design went live, this means Android.stackexchange has officially graduated and is no longer a Beta site. Congrats!

If you see any CSS/Styling issues, please start a new question for the bug report, and tag it with "Design" and "Bug." It will be a lot easier for me to track new questions than reading the comments replied to this thread.

The favicons may be cached by your browsers, to see the new ones, load the following URL in your browser's address bar and hard refresh.

http://sstatic.net/android/img/favicon.ico

http://sstatic.net/androidmeta/img/favicon.ico

This site's [twitter account](http://twitter.com/#!/stackandroid) and [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android) also got a facelift as well! Check them out.

I hope you enjoy the new site, I'm very excited for you. Thank you for being an awesome community, and congratulations!

<sub>P.S. there's an easter egg on the site somewhere. It's something we've never done before. See if you can find it.</sub>

Comment: Looks awesome! Great Job

Comment: Re the easter egg: Does the crazy dancing droid on the error page count?

Comment: Love the look of the site!

Comment: @Jin Beautiful design, you really hit this one out of the park.

Comment: To all involved in the redesign...Good Job!  Looks great.

Comment: thanks guys. yes the easter egg is the dancing robot video on the /error page.

Comment: ABSO-FRAKKIN-LUTELY LOVE IT!!!  :) Good Job!

Answer (score 2):

@Jin: Absolutely immense job on the new design. Well done, indeed!

I am of the personal opinion that the ASK QUESTION link, although highlighted in green doesn't really stand out - it tends to merge with the grey background. Could that be changed so as to better display the link? Also, when a user hovers over the link - it tends to fade away.

Comment: @spark Thanks. I say you give it some time. Personally I don't think it's an issue. On many of the SE sites I've done I didn't put too much emphasis on the Ask link and people seemed to have np finding it, even the header layout changed quite a bit from the Beta theme. The Android site header layout is very similar to the Beta theme. Logo left, nav links right.

Comment: Sure. *I* already know where it is, anyhow. :P