# How about making the header bar and logo green like the Android mascot, instead of blue?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

I feel like people may get the impression that something is wrong with this site because the major color highlight (from the header bar) is blue, which used to be the Windows Phone OS color, and Android is commonly known as the "green" mobile OS.

Here's a visual example of how it could be improved with 2 simple css rules:

```
.site-header {
    background-color: HSL(80, 90%, 47%);
}

.site-header img {
    filter: hue-rotate(120deg) invert(100%);
}
```

[image: proposed recolor example]

If rendered to an image, no CSS would be required. Since this is just a recolor, essentially, it shouldn't take a long time to think this over with a designer. What do you think?

Comment: I personally want to see a design overhaul, may be something artistic, like what [anime.se], [workplace.se] and [worldbuilding.se] have. Ever since 2015 , when they introduced this new design, I have tried hard but continued to find the design uninspiring. The problem is that we are a technology site, and I don't see any technology site looking aesthically appealing compared to culture / recreation and life / arts websites in SE network, so I don't know what exactly I am looking for.

Comment: I guess it's a dupe of https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2560/44325, https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2464/44325, and https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1918/44325...

Comment: @Firelord I believe the blue color was certainly influenced by Google's Material Design and how it's so blue (that even [the official Android Developer site uses it](https://developer.android.com/docs) and it's [the default toolbar color for a new Flutter project](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab#step-1-create-the-starter-flutter-app))

Comment: @AndrewT. first time I am seeing Android dev site in blue. I always got specific results from the web  for that website and the blue color was not predominant in such pages. Than there is source.android.com missing the blue, so I have had a different experience, lacking blue most of the time. But yeah, you make a good point. It is probable the designers were influenced by Google's MD.

Comment: As far as I know, Anime&Manga site design had been in the works and reworks and delays for many years, but in the end the company bought what you see and it took roughly 3-4 months to implement (I can be wrong about the final attempt duration). So maybe if you find a designer for hire and refer them to SE to contract, to minimize effort on their part, it's more likely to get done imo than if we just do nothing and wait forever.

Comment: My workaround has been: .site-header { display: none; }. I like less clutter... and scrolling. :)

Comment: @Firelord I think an open letter on the MSE would have some (little) chance. If it is only a 2-line css change, more than little.