# The Android Logo Color Mismatch

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

I am a stranger to the saloon but I want to give an advice.

When I enter the site. The Mr Android has a shade of blue on the banner but the tab icon has green one.

I think it looks bad. Plus since when Android wore blue?

I think the original green Mr Android should be brought back

Comment: The blue color has been mentioned on the duplicate since April 2015 (on [this answer](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1906/44325) and [this answer](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1918/44325)), but there was no response from SE design team.